# When to set debug configuration for archiving an iOS app?

Tags: ios, debugging, release, archive, beta

I'm reading the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) and, in the "Beta Testing Your iOS App" section and in its "Archiving and Validating your App" subsection, talking about the Archive scheme settings it is said:

> From the Build Configuration pop-up menu, choose Release, and click Close.

My question is: if you need to set the Archive's build configuration to "Release" even for distributing your app for testing, both ad hoc deployment and TestFlight distribution, when could it be useful to set the configuration to "Debug"? You don't really need to archive the project to install it in your devices during development.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much benefit putting a test version in a Debug archive. When it is already in the archive there isn't much console debugging you can do with Xcode. At least none that I know of.

Testing an archive in release version is the way to go, in the end the application will be published in a release configuration for distribution, testing it on release is the most sensible thing. Some behaviors in Debug are different in Release, testing a distribution archive in release is the most useful IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can export IPA signed with development certificate and test different services (like push or in-app) in a sandbox. 
I don't know if it is permitted at the moment but previously you could distribute development builds to real devices the same way as adhoc. Maybe it's just a deprecated functionality.